# Google Apps Script create Google Doc and then save blob to PDF not working even after saveAndClose()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to copy a google doc (which is a template), save it as a new file name, add text to the doc, add an image to the doc, then make a pdf copy of the doc.

I can get the doc to copy, add the text, add the image, and that works fine. Then I add the line to convert to blob to create the pdf but the pdf is now just what the template was before the text and image are added. So then I do save and close and then re-open the doc and then do the convert to blob pdf - but in this case the text and image of the doc are blank and the pdf is blank. I have tried multiple iterations of save and close and re-open before creating the pdf. I don't know why it's not working properly.

```
  // Create template copy:
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderID); // Get folder with specified destinationFolderID
  const copiedTemplateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(templateGoogleDocumentID).makeCopy("file name xyz", folder); // Copy template to destination folder
  const docId = copiedTemplateDoc.getId();
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
  const header = doc.getHeader();
  const body = doc.getBody();
                                    
  // Insert photo    
  if(imageURL) {
    const imageBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(imageURL).getBlob();
    const totalElements = doc.getNumChildren();
    const el=[]
    for(var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j) {
      const element = doc.getChild(j);
      const type = element.getType();
      if (type =='PARAGRAPH'){
        el[j]=element.getText()
        if(el[j]=='{Photo}'){
          element.removeFromParent();
          const styles = {};
          styles[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;
          doc.insertImage(j, imageBlob).setHeight('144').getParent().setAttributes(styles);
        }
      }
    }  
  }

  doc.saveAndClose() // the doc must be saved and closed before it can be converted to a pdf
  DocumentApp.openById(docId);
  const testPDF = DriveApp.createFile(doc.getBlob()).moveTo(folder); // Export a PDF copy of the Lead Sheet doc to the SREC drive folder
```

Comment: use this : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getAs(String)  and then with the blob use this : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFile(BlobSource)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+create+Google+Doc+save+blob+to+PDF

Comment: Believe me I've searched for over an hour for a solution. I've done getBlob() and I've tried getAs('application/pdf') and neither are working - even with different combinations and permutations of saving and re-opening the file

Comment: Not sure if related, but you are doing nothing with the opened document. You should reassign it to a variable:  Change `DocumentApp.openById(docId);` to `doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);`